# retrieve an optional value swift

Tags: image, swift, parse-platform, option-type

I have this function:

```
func richiamoImmagine()
{
    let avatarFile = PFUser.currentUser()!["Avatar"] as! PFFile
    avatarFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let finalimage = UIImage(data: imageData!) {
                self.avatarImage.image = finalimage
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which retrive an image from parse but if the user doesn't have any image the function cause a crash and this error appear in the log:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I know I have to put something like:

```
if let "variable" == avatarFile
```

so if the function retrieve nothing at least it doesn't make my app crash! How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Just don't use exclamation marks. They mean "I can crash!"

Comment: but i have to replace it with a "?" and in the line below i have to put the "!" because of xcode want it! and the app still crash!

Comment: Generally speaking, using the forced unwrapping operator `!` __doesn't magically make an optional not nil__. Use it wisely, and if not sure, just avoid it and try to play with optional binding and optional chanining

Comment: "and in the line below i have to put the "!" " No you don't. You never _have_ to put `!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the place where the crash happens is in this line:

```
if let finalimage = UIImage(data: imageData!) {
```

because you're using the forced unwrapping operator. I would add a quick check to the preceding `if` statement to check for not nil:

```
if error == nil && imageData != nil {
```

or even better use *optional binding*:

```
if let imageData = imageData where error == nil {
    if let finalimage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
        self.avatarImage.image = finalimage
    }
}
```

---

Update: if the error happens in the first line, then you should (again) use optional binding to protect against undesired crashes:

```
if let avatarFile = PFUser.currentUser()?["Avatar"] as? PFFile {

}
```

Comment: Xcode says the error is in the first line:  let avatarFile = PFUser.currentUser()!["Avatar"] as! PFFile